# Business model property's lazy loading with ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, lazy-loading, asp.net-core-1.1

I would like to implement the lazy loading on some properties in my business models. 
How is the best way to do that with ASP.NET Core ? Inject the database context into my model and querying it when the property is used ? Or implement a generic method like *void LazyLoadProperty(string propertyName, ApplicationDbContext dbContext)* on my model and inject the database context each time I need a lazy loaded value ?

For information I'm using *.NETCoreApp1.1* and *Entity Framework Core*.

Comment: Why would you want lazy loading in a web app anyway?

Comment: because some properties needs complex queries with multiple joins to get the value, a value I rarely need, so I would like to load them only when I need it

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

There you will find a the blurb about lazy loading - not yet possible with EFC yet.... its on Backlog

Answer (score 2):

When doing lazy loading of data for my business models I use the approach of making the business model aware of the database context and then having the property lazy load the data when the property is accessed if the data for that property hasn't yet been lazy loaded.  I find that this method works really well.

Comment: So your business model knows your database context, isn't it ? How do you pass your database context to your business model ? By the constructor ?

Comment: While I am a fan of selective unit testing, I'm very pragmatic about how I allocate my development effort.  So in my case I explicitly code access to the database context into the business model.  Passing it in via a constructor is another options and is often favored by developers who are registering the business model into a Dependency Injection container which I prefer not to do.